# react-i18next сбивается при перезагрузке страницы

Tags: reactjs, react-hook, i18n, перевод

При перезагрузке страницы сбивается перевод
И вместо, например, **'settings'** в компонент выводится **"TRANSLATION.COMPONENTS.SIDEBAR.SETTINGS"**

Причём, перевод сбивается если перезагрузка страницы происходит не от корня приложения

Например:
http://localhost:8080/account (всё ок)
http://localhost:8080/account/some-user-id/items (сбивается)

Если переходить "вручную", через ссылки в `react-router-dom`, тогда всё ок
А если перезагрузить страницу, то перевод ломается

В компонентах использую хук `useTranslation`

Как это фиксится?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в пути при инициализации **i18n**
Перевод перестал сбиваться при перезагрузке когда добавил слэш в `backend.loadPath`
Было:
`loadPath: 'public/locales/{{lng}}/translation.json'`

Стало:
`loadPath: '/public/locales/{{lng}}/translation.json'`

```
i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    supportedLngs: languages,
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    debug: false,
    react: {
      useSuspense: false,
    },
    backend: {
      loadPath: '/public/locales/{{lng}}/translation.json',
    },
    detection: {
      order: ['cookie', 'localStorage'],
      caches: ['cookie'],
    },
  })
```